# How can I make the color of an EditText styleable with a custom attribute (like an error)?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-custom-view, textcolor, declare-styleable

I'd like to make an EditText whose text turns red when an "error" condition is met. I'm aware that TextInputLayout has a built-in error state, but I don't want to have text beneath the input area, and I don't want to include the support design libraries in my project (which is an sdk - so others will include it). However, my EditText *always* shows the error state, and I'm out of ideas as to why.

My efforts thus far:

To begin, I declare a styleable thing. Seems fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MySpecialEditText">
        <attr name="state_error" format="boolean"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then I create a selector in my `res/colors` directory. Now, I'd really prefer to only override the color if  my special attribute is set. But if I have to copy over the `android:state-pressed`, etc, states and every combination thereof, I can do that (and have, with the same results, see below). This file is `res/color/red_on_error_dark.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.mypackage">
    <item
        custom:state_error="true"
        android:color="#f00" />
    <item
        custom:state_error="false"
        android:color="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>
</selector>
```

And I add my new stylish thing to the XML inclusion of my custom class:

```
<com.mypackage.MySpecialEditText
     android:id="@+id/some_id"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:hint="@string/a_nice_hint"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:textColor="@color/red_on_error_dark"
     />
```

So far, so good. Now, I create my class that extends EditText:

```
public class MySpecialEditText extends EditText {

    private static final int[] STATE_ERROR = {R.attr.state_error};
    private boolean mStateError;
    //... lots of other fun functionality

    // Time to set my custom status
    public void setStateError(boolean stateError) {
        mStateError = stateError;
        invalidate();
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    // And now, I need to add the custom state drawable.
    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (mStateError) {    
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_ERROR);
        } 
        return drawableState;
    }
}
```

All of this is easy enough to put together. However, when I run the code, it always draws the text as red.

Things I have verified:

1. That I'm correctly setting the error/no-error states.
2. That the code is going through the `onCreateDrawableState` method during the non-error times! It skips the `mergeDrawableStates` method with the extra attribute. (I have also added an `else` clause and returned a drawableState with no added extra spaces).
3. Even though the attribute is boolean, and should theoretically be able to accept a value of true or false, I've added a separate attr `STATE_VALID`, and changed my selector to be as follows.

I have even gone so far as to change the selector to the exhaustive:

```
<item custom:state_error="true" android:state_selected="true" android:color="#f00" />
<item custom:state_error="true" android:state_focused="true" android:color="#f00" />
<item custom:state_error="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#f00" />

<item custom:state_error="false" android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />
<item custom:state_error="false" android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />
<item custom:state_error="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />
```

And I've gone one farther and combined the unnecessary-extra-state with a bunch of `android:state_blah`, so I have something like 20 different cases in my selector. (Actually, in that case, it always stays white, which isn't much better).

Now, what I'd really, really like is to declare a styleable value that other people (who use my sdk) can set a value to if they so choose. But for now I'll be happy to know why the text is always red.

Edit: One totally legit workaround is simply to call setTextColor when I reach an error state in `MySpecialEditText`. This is my interim solution, but it prevents someone from using my control and adding a `custom:state_error=@color/some_custom_color`, or a similar value in theme of their choosing. So long as I'm calling setTextColor by hand, the error color is always my particular shade of red.

I could go further and add a new constructor or setter for the error color, but that's not a very nice solution for a library. If you use the library and instantiate my control, it will pick up all the `EditText` styles you already have, so it looks native. And if you want to customize the error color, I'd love for you to be able to do that in one place for your whole app with a nice piece of XML that you can run by a designer.

Any ideas? A pre-emptive thank you to all answerers and attempted answerers.

Comment: Why don't you just set the colour of your EditText when the error occurres?

Comment: I can just change the text color when the error occurs, and that's actually the only way I've gotten close to my desired functionality. The problem with that, though, is that I can't let someone else set what the error color should be -- my project is a library, so extensibility is helpful. I've also had mixed results on caching and picking up the old color (getColor wants you to add a theme now), but I didn't go very far down that rabbit hole, so it's likely I missed something simple.